# Mastermind in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to implement in python Donald Knuth's algorithm for codebreaking mastermind in not more than 5 moves. I have checked my code several times, and it seems to follow the algorithm, as its stated here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)#Five-guess_algorithm

However, I get that some of the secrets take 7 or even 8 moves to accomplish, such as  [5, 4, 4, 5].

Here is the code:

```
# returns how many bulls and cows
def HowManyBc(guess,secret):
    invalid=max(guess)+1
    bulls=0
    cows=0
    r=0
    while r<4:
        if guess[r]==secret[r]:
            bulls=bulls+1
            secret[r]=invalid
            guess[r]=invalid
        r=r+1
    r=0
    while r<4:
        p=0
        while p<4:
            if guess[r]==secret[p] and guess[r]!=invalid:
                cows=cows+1
                secret[p]=invalid
                break
            p=p+1
        r=r+1          
    return [bulls,cows]

# sends every BC to its index in HMList
def Adjustment(BC1):
    if BC1==[0,0]:
        return 0
    elif BC1==[0,1]:
        return 1
    elif BC1==[0,2]:
        return 2
    elif BC1==[0,3]:
        return 3
    elif BC1==[0,4]:
        return 4
    elif BC1==[1,0]:
        return 5
    elif BC1==[1,1]:
        return 6
    elif BC1==[1,2]:
        return 7
    elif BC1==[1,3]:
        return 8
    elif BC1==[2,0]:
        return 9
    elif BC1==[2,1]:
        return 10
    elif BC1==[2,2]:
        return 11
    elif BC1==[3,0]:
        return 12
    elif BC1==[4,0]:
        return 13  
# returns positive's list minimum without including zeros    
def MinimumNozeros(List1):
    minimum=max(List1)+1
    for item in List1:
        if item!=0 and item<minimum:
            minimum=item
    return minimum

TempList=[[5, 4, 4, 5]]

for secret in TempList:
    guess=[0,0,1,1]
    BC=HowManyBc(guess[:],secret[:])
    counter=1
    optionList=[]
    allList=[]
    for i0 in range(0,6):
        for i1 in range(0,6):
            for i2 in range(0,6):
                for i3 in range(0,6):
                    optionList.append([i0,i1,i2,i3])
                    allList.append([i0,i1,i2,i3])
    while BC!=[4,0]:
        dummyList=[]
        for i0 in range(0,6):
            for i1 in range(0,6):
                for i2 in range(0,6):
                    for i3 in range(0,6):
                        opSecret=[i0,i1,i2,i3]
                        if HowManyBc(guess[:],opSecret[:])==BC:
                            dummyList.append(opSecret)
        List1=[item for item in optionList if item in dummyList]
        optionList=List1[:]
        nextGuess1=[]
        item1Max=0
        L1=optionList[:]
        L2=allList[:]
        for item1 in L1:
            ListBC=[]
            for item2 in L2:
                ListBC.append(HowManyBc(item1[:],item2[:]))
            HMList=[0]*14 # how many times every possible BC appeared
            for BC1 in ListBC:
                index=Adjustment(BC1)
                HMList[index]=HMList[index]+1
            m=MinimumNozeros(HMList[:])
            if m>item1Max:
                item1Max=m
                nextGuess1=item1[:]
        guess=nextGuess1[:]
        BC=HowManyBc(guess[:],secret[:])
        counter=counter+1
```

Can someone help?

Thanks,Mike

Answer (score 3):

Knuth's algorithm is:

1. Create a set S of remaining possibilities (at this point there are 1296). The first guess is aabb.
2. Remove all possibilities from S that would not give the same score of colored and white pegs if they were the answer.
3. For each possible guess (not necessarily in S) calculate how many possibilities from S would be eliminated for each possible colored/white score. The score of the guess is the least of such values. Play the guess with the highest score (minimax).
4. Go back to step 2 until you have got it right.

Your algorithm is:

1. Create a set S of remaining possibilities (at this point there are 1296). The first guess is aabb.
2. Remove all possibilities from S that would not give the same score of colored and white pegs if they were the answer.
3. For each possible guess (**that has to be in S**) calculate how many possibilities from the set of **all options** would **remain** for each possible colored/white score. The score of the guess is the least of such values. Play the guess with the highest score (minimax).
4. Go back to step 2 until you have got it right.

You can fix this by changing the loop to:

```
for secret in TempList:
    guess=[0,0,1,1]
    BC=HowManyBc(guess[:],secret[:])
    counter=1
    optionList=[]
    allList=[]
    for i0 in range(0,6):
        for i1 in range(0,6):
            for i2 in range(0,6):
                for i3 in range(0,6):
                    optionList.append([i0,i1,i2,i3])
                    allList.append([i0,i1,i2,i3])
    #while BC!=[4,0]:
    while len(optionList)>1:
        dummyList=[]
        for i0 in range(0,6):
            for i1 in range(0,6):
                for i2 in range(0,6):
                    for i3 in range(0,6):
                        opSecret=[i0,i1,i2,i3]
                        if HowManyBc(guess[:],opSecret[:])==BC:
                            dummyList.append(opSecret)
        List1=[item for item in optionList if item in dummyList]
        optionList=List1[:]
        nextGuess1=[]
        item1Max=0
        #L1=optionList[:]
        #L2=allList[:]
        L2=optionList[:]
        L1=allList[:]
        for item1 in L1: 
            ListBC=[]
            for item2 in L2: 
                ListBC.append(HowManyBc(item1[:],item2[:]))
            HMList=[0]*14 
            for BC1 in ListBC:
                index=Adjustment(BC1)
                HMList[index]=HMList[index]+1  
            #m=MinimumNozeros(HMList[:])
            m=len(L1)-max(HMList[:]) 
            if m>item1Max:
                item1Max=m
                nextGuess1=item1[:]
        guess=nextGuess1[:]
        BC=HowManyBc(guess[:],secret[:])
        counter=counter+1
print optionList
```

Comment: Another thing: can this algorithm be improved? right now it runs very slow - for all possible 1296 secrets it takes something like 40 minutes. I am required to do it much faster.

Comment: Use the built in [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) type for a start rather than doing things like `List1=[item for item in optionList if item in dummyList]`

Comment: The thing is, I actually have to write it on C. I did it on python since it is easier with the lists and others things in python. I need to make the algorithm itself faster (less moves, less checks...).

Comment: Probably fastest runtime is to use Python to precompute a decision tree showing which guess to make in every situation.  Based on the score of bulls and cows you can choose which subtree to move to.  This would execute in microseconds and only use a few kbytes of RAM :)

Comment: Can you elaborate? How can I do it and on C?

Comment: I don't really understand the step 2